# Git: move local project into other repo, keeping history

Tags: git, github

I need to somehow move an existing maven project which is under version control with git, inside another git repo where already another project resides.

Why? In the past few weeks, I worked on a project on my own. I use git locally (there is *no* remote repository!) to track my changes. So the basic structure on my side is this:

```
myRepo
  |--.git
  |--myProject
  |--.gitignore
```

where `myProject` is a maven project.

Meanwhile, a colleague of mine created a repo himself, also maven, with another project in it. This repo is remote, on GitHub. The structure looks like this:

```
commonRepo
  |--.git
  |--hisProject
  |--.gitignore
  |--pom.xml
  |--.project
  |--.settings
```

So as you can see, the idea is that there is a parent pom in this repo which specifies all the modules. `hisPoject` is one of these modules.

I now want to move `myProject` there, which will then be another maven module. I don't want to lose my commit history in the process. So I want the final structure to look like:

```
commonRepo
  |--.git
  |--hisProject
  |--myProject
  |--.gitignore
  |--pom.xml
  |--.project
  |--.settings
```

I found some approaches to move one directory into another repo, but it seems that none of these fit perfectly to my problem. Looks like those solutions require `myRepo` to have a remote and then pull it into `commonRepo` and merge.

So, how is it possible to accomplish what I want?

Comment: why java and maven??

Comment: I didn't know if it was relevant what kind of projects they are. But I see that they can be just treated as files and folders in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `myRepo` and `commonRepo` are accessible from the same machine, do the following:

```
cd /path/to/commonRepo
git remote add -f other_repo /path/to/myRepo
git merge other_repo/master

# The following commands need to be executed only if there are conflicts.
# Your description suggests that the only conflict may be in .gitignore.
# Run these commands after resolving the conflicts manually.
git add .
git commit -m "Merged with myRepo"
# End of commands needed in case of conflicts

git remote remove other_repo
```